# Get jQuery object from table row click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check out the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hh5jg/1).  This JavaScript will take the row that a user clicks on and make an object with the key coming from the `thead` element in the table and the value coming from the data in the text in the table cell value.  I'm looking for a more professional/succint way of doing this:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('tr').click(function () {
                var tableData = $(this).children('td').map(function () {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get();
                var props = $('thead > tr th');
                var array = [];
                props.each(function () { array.push($(this).text()) });
                //keys
                console.log(array);
                //values
                console.log(tableData);

                var obj = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
                    obj[array[i]] = tableData[i];
                }
                console.log(obj);
            });

        });
```

HTML

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">PersonId</th><th scope="col">FirstName</th><th scope="col">LastName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Doe</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>2</td><td>Jane</td><td>Doe</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>3</td><td>Time</td><td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `$('thead > tr th')` is not specific enough, if you have multiple tables in the page.  You want the headings of the same table that was clicked: `$(this).closest('table').find('thead > tr th')`.

`var array` is an unsatisfying name.  I can see that it's an array — but what does it do?  How about calling it `tableHeadings`?

You formed `tableData` using `Array.map()`; why not do the headings the same way?

```
var tableHeadings = $(this).closest('table')
                           .find('thead > tr th')
                           .map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```